# Secure Rest API

Tags: jquery, python, api, rest, oauth

I'm trying to figure whats the best aproach to secure a REST api without using OAuth or another similar system. I read about using ApiKeys in every request, I think this could be the best in my case, but I'm not sure how to implement it.
I'm using Python with Flask in the server side and JQuery in the client side. This API must be accesible with web and mobile and for private use.
I will use Amazon as a Server.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Basic authentication over HTTPs](http://apiux.com/2013/03/21/authentication-dont-be-clever/).

Comment: One might add: make sure you also do not accept connections over HTTP.